# android 2.1 AsyncTask file download not working for multiple thread work fine when call single instance

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i am using android 2.1 ,api level 7 and try to implement asynchronous file download from LAN server 
for this i am trying to implement AsyncTask .When i am trying to call a single thread it works find but when call  multiple its just stop both the thread

```
  /* AsyncTask class*/  
          class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {        
                    super.onPreExecute();       
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

                    int count;

                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                        Log.i("count","in");
                        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                        Log.i("count","in1");
                        conexion.connect();
                        Log.i("count","in2");
                        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        Log.i("count","in3");
                        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                        Log.i("count","in4");        
                        BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                        Log.i("count","in5");
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/video" +aurl[1] +".mp4");
                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                        long total = 0;
                        Log.i("count","in6");
                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                            //Log.i("count","in7");
                            total += count;
                            Log.i("count",aurl[1]);
                            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }
                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        input.close();          
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {        
                    Log.i("progress",progress[0]);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {        
                    Log.i("process","end");       
                }
            } 

  /*main method call*/
private void startDownload() {
        Log.v("count","out");
        String url = lanurl+"titanic/video"+1+"_en.m4v";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url,"1");

        url = lanurl+"titanic/video"+2+"_en.m4v";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url,"2");

    }
output :
download both file in sd card
but no file downloading properly
```

Comment: please paste the whole logcat for this.

Comment: 03-17 13:55:30.554: W/AudioPolicyManager(1315): getSituationVolume() mSituationVolume=0.500000
03-17 13:55:30.554: E/AudioPolicyManager(1315): Speaker_swa Volume = 0.000000 , device = 2, stream = 1, index = 0
03-17 13:55:30.562: I/count(7852): in
03-17 13:55:30.570: I/count(7852): in
03-17 13:55:30.601: I/count(7852): in1
03-17 13:55:30.617: I/count(7852): in1
03-17 13:55:30.726: I/count(7852): in2
03-17 13:55:30.726: I/count(7852): in2
03-17 13:55:30.726: I/count(7852): in3
03-17 13:55:30.726: I/count(7852): in3
03-17 13:55:30.750: I/count(7852): in4
03-17 13:55:30.757: I/count(7852): in4

Comment: 03-17 13:55:33.375: I/WindowOrientationListener(1487): orientation 60.139717 gives new rotation = 1
03-17 13:55:33.375: I/OrientationDebug(1487): [pwm] in MyOrientationListener.onOrientationChanged() rotation=1  mFancyRotationAnimation=0   now call mWindowManager.setRotation()
03-17 13:55:33.375: I/OrientationDebug(1487): [wms] in setRotation() rotation=1 alwaysSendConfiguration=false animFlags=0
03-17 13:55:33.375: I/OrientationDebug(1487): [wms] in setRotation() now call setRotationUnchecked()
03-17 13:55:33.375: I/WindowManager(1487): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=0

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the complete Question. But seems like your problem is with AsyncTask.

Single Object created for an AsyncTask can be used only once. If you want to use it again, you need to create an another object for the same AsyncTask.

Comment: private void startDownload() {
        Log.v("count","out");
        String url = lanurl+"titanic/video"+1+"_en.m4v";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url,"1");

        url = lanurl+"titanic/video"+2+"_en.m4v";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url,"2");

    }

Comment: Try starting the new one in the postExecute of the previous one. So at a time Single Network connection will be maintained.

Comment: Do you mean to continue with multiple connections ?

Comment: Try using the ThreadPoolExecutor at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: i am using  asynctask to update progress bar in view .i don't think ThreadPoolExecutor can update progress bar view asynchronously .and in my log it print >>in4<<< for both the thread  just before the BufferedInputStream

Comment: I can't understand what is >>in4<<. i didn't observed this any where at anytime. Can you paste Code snippet. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: sorry for that its the log i have written in doInBackground method in asynctask

Comment: URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                        Log.i("count","in1");
                        conexion.connect();
                        Log.i("count","in2");
                        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        Log.i("count","in3");
                        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                        Log.i("count","in4");        
                        BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

Comment: Try below Code

URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
          URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
          conn.connect();
          InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
          image_drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, url.toString());
          is.close();

Comment: Why are you calculating Content Length ?

Comment: onProgressUpdate method i will set the progress  bar for that i am calculate that %

Comment: OK Fine.This is typical to handle this type of loading progress. that's why most of the applications will show a normal loading bar with out any progress number.not even Google default apps,facebook ,twitter also.

Comment: any solution or suggestion for this or links that  can help

Comment: Its better if you can use a service which downloads all the Images in the background using the asyncTask. If you want an example for this, please click here for more info https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service.

Comment: means call asynctask in ThreadPoolExecutor it will not solve the progress bar issue i think

Comment: Why cant You follow my previous comment starting AsyncTasks one by one  ? In My project i even used no of AsyncTasks at a time for fetching Images from Server which is working fine for me. Please check my blog http://pavandroid.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-create-calendar-in-android.html where i kept the src for displaying simple ListView with different Images fetching  from different URL's at a time using AsyncTask.

Comment: thanks for link , i am  trying to implement this in my project and get back to you

Comment: I think books.xml used in that link is not available now. Plese use the link https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2qCFbmeiTFxNDFhZDRiNjQtMTJiNC00MzkyLTg5NzItOTcxOWNjN2U4NWVi for this xml.Either you can host it some where and can give that link in this project or you can keep it in XML folder in res folder and use this from the project.

Comment: Hey just click on File and download it. you will get a XML file or else gimme your mail id quickly then i can share it directly